# explicit solution to linear PDE -- boundary value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am looking for an explicit, closed form expression for the solution to a boundary value problem given by the linear PDE:

$$
u_{xx}+au_y-bu+c=0
$$
with the BCs
$ u_x(-g,y)=ku $, $u_x(g,y)=-ku$, $ u(x,0)=u_0 $, $u(x,d)=u_d$.

$a,b,c,k,u_0$ and $u_d$ are all $>0$.
What would be the best thing to do with this? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: A linear equation with constant coefficients set on a domain of very simple geometry, well, this appeals to Fourier series.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that road!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for the terms $-bu + c$, your pde is the heat equation, where $y$ plays the role of "time".
It can be transformed to the heat equation by 
$u = e^{by/a} v + c/b$.  But you have one  boundary condition too many:
you can't specify boundary conditions at both $y=0$ and $y=d$.

Comment: Let me put it this way.  The boundary condition at $y=0$ determines $u(x,0)$ up to an additive constant.  The value of $u(x,0)$ and the boundary conditions at $x = \pm g$ then determine $u(x,y)$ for all $y > 0$.  It's very unlikely that this will satisfy your boundary condition at $y=d$.  So if you can't drop the other boundary condition, your problem will have no solution.

Comment: That is an elliptic equation, second order in $y$.  Your pde is parabolic, first order in $y$.  That's not at all similar.